# Firebase imageview array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

in my app, I am using a custom image array view. A number of images the user uploads per post should be a number of images displayed in a carousel-like manner.

In firebase, I have values from image to imageFive

```
{
  "image" : "W585B.jpg",
  "imageFive" : "",
  "imageFour" : "",
  "imageThree" : "",
  "imageTwo" : "",
}
```

As you can see in this example only one value has a string in it. The users have the ability to post one to five images. I want to append however many images the user uploads and display them in a carousel. Here's what I have right now.

```
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

           if let stringImage = self.imageNames {



        let imageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage)")

        imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {


                self.ImageOne = UIImage(data: data!)!
                imageArray.append(self.ImageOne)

            }else {
                print("Error downloading image:" )
            }


            self.carouselView.reloadData()

            self.carouselView.type = .rotary



            if let stringImages = self.imagesTwo {

                let imageRefs = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImages)")

                imageRefs.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        self.ImageTwo = UIImage(data: data!)!
                        imageArray.append(self.ImageTwo)


                    }else {
                        print("Error downloading image:" )
                    }
                    self.carouselView.reloadData()

                    self.carouselView.type = .rotary


                })}
            if let stringImage3 = self.imagesThree {

                let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage3)")

                imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        self.ImageThree = UIImage(data: data!)!
                        imageArray.append(self.ImageThree)


                    }else {
                        print("Error downloading image:" )
                    }

                    self.carouselView.reloadData()

                    self.carouselView.type = .rotary

                })}
            if let stringImage4 = self.imagesFour {

                let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage4)")

                imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        self.ImageFour = UIImage(data: data!)!
                        imageArray.append(self.ImageFour)


                    }else {
                        print("Error downloading image:" )
                    }

                    self.carouselView.reloadData()

                    self.carouselView.type = .rotary

                })}
            if let stringImage5 = self.imagesFive {
               // AppDelegate.instance().showActivityIndicator()
                let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage5)")

                imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                      //  AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicator()
                        self.ImageFive = UIImage(data: data!)!
                        imageArray.append(self.ImageFive)


                    }else {
                        print("Error downloading image:" )
                    }
                    self.carouselView.reloadData()

                    self.carouselView.type = .rotary


                })}

        })

    }

 func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var imageView: UIImageView!

        if view == nil {
            imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 250, height: 270))
           // imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            carousel.clipsToBounds = true
        }else{
            imageView = view as! UIImageView

        }


        imageView.image = imageArray[index]
        imageArray.removeAll()

        return imageView


    }
```

Right now, I have to click the cell twice in order for the image to show. When I click the cell once it shows nothing but then it shows the image on the second click. Similarly, if I click another cell, it shows the image of the previous cell on the first click and then on the second click, it shows the image for that cell.

Also when I click on a cell with multiple images, on the first click it shows nothing, on the second click, the app crashes and says **fatal error: Index out of range**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but You can try this too:

```
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    var imageView = view as! UIImageView

    if view != nil {
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 250, height: 270))
       // imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        carousel.clipsToBounds = true

       imageView = view as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = imageArray[index]
        imageArray.removeAll() // are you sure about this line?
}
        return imageView
    }
```

Comment: I kinda figured everything out except the imageArray.removeAll() line. I put it there because when I go from one cell to another, the images would append. So images from cell one would append to images in cell two and will be displayed in the carousel, which I don't want but now  imageArray.removeAll() isn't working.

Comment: I updated my code to what I have so far. So I am now getting the images on the first click. The only problem now like I just stated is the cell images appending